# How to move elements along with a curve and appear one by one by js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to match up the word(image one by one) overlap its background which is a curve/arch, and the element should appear consecutively. So far I can only use gif,make the animation, overlap the bg image, I tried slide or other effect but doesn't give the animation i want, please reference some good way to do this instead of gif..
Also, is there any tips that could make the components don't go off but the exact position even with different browser size? Thanks a lot for the help!

```js
$(function(){$('.woodpanel').hide();}); 
setTimeout(function(){$(".woodpanel").effect('bounce', 1200);},2000); 
$(function(){$('.slogantext').hide();}); 
    
    

setTimeout(function(){ $(".slogantext").toggle("slow","top");},2400);
```

```html
<div class="woodpanel" style="width: 1270px; position:absolute; top:2%;left:50%;margin-left:-635px;text-align: center;">
<img id="woodbg" src="https://app.box.com/shared/static/4hxnuu5nl1m0xtmamx97qh7z0dp99rpo.png"
    style="overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto;"alt="woodbg">
  <div class="slogantext" style="overflow:hidden;display:block;position:absolute;margin-top:-235px;margin-left:135px;z-index:7;">
<img src="https://app.box.com/shared/static/hxjovfl51r7ooqs3jm30xp5za97hsph1.gif" alt="woodwordtest"style="width:100%;"></div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: do you want to show text only on arc ?

Comment: yes, the text should be in the mid of arc. and text shall appear one by one. i did match text div some width as arc width